# How do people free all the memory before an exception exit?

Tags: c++, memory

Is there an easy way of freeing all the memory when I am exiting due to an error in the program? I don't want to free every single allocation, as it's hard to keep track of all of them. And how do the experienced developers that work with C++ approach this problem?

Comment: exiting the whole program: the OS does it automatically. Exiting a function: RAII.

Comment: The OS doesn't really free the memory.  The memory pointers are reset for the next program.

Comment: *"it's hard to keep track of all of them."* Not with smart pointers and other RAII objects.

Comment: note that while memory isn't that important once you terminate, RAII is more general than that, it helps you to "free" any resource, eg you might want to write things to a file as part of shutting down your program, and that can be considered as a resource that needs to be managed.

Comment: Usually, when there is a serious error in the program, the nice OSes will dump information to the console or to a file before fully terminating the program.  Sometimes you can attach a debugger so that the OS will call the debugger before killing the program.

Comment: There is no need to free memory when exiting. In a single threaded application, RAII may be enough to free everything automatically. But on a complex multi-threaded UI application, my experience shows that in fact it is best *not to try* freeing any memory at exit, because that could yield to a crash due to thread dependencies. The user probably won't see the difference, but iOS (for example) will count that as a crash and report it to developer. So we prefer to call `_Exit` [doc here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/_Exit)

Answer (score 4):

RAII is a technique where all resources are owned by objects that have destructors, except objects that exist directly in automatic (stack) and static/global storage.

When an exception occurs that isn't unhandled, C++ guarantees your program will unroll the stack, destroying each object on the stack in turn.

When you exit main, C++ guarantees that objects of static/global storage duration get destroyed as well.

Done properly, every resource you allocated is cleaned up.

This requires some discipline, and is often worth it.

Now, you can rely on the fact that modern OS's recycle memory and file handle resources that your program acquires while running, and just exit your program.

This is a lot easier.  But it has serious limitations.

Not every program has resources that are cleaned up by an OS.  If you are negotiating with a server for some resource, your OS cleanup won't work.  If you create some kinds of a named pipes, your OS cleanup won't work.  If you make some kinds of temporary files, your OS cleanup won't work.

In addition, exiting out of part of a program is a lot like exiting the program as a whole.  So proper RAII cleanup in each part results in entire programs that clean themselves up when they shut down.

RAII is "resource allocation is initialization".  The simplest case is a `std::unique_ptr<T>`, where you do this:

```
std::unique_ptr<int> pint = std::make_unique<int>(3);
```

now `pint` has a pointer to the allocated `int` whose value is `3`.  Its ownership can be *moved* to another `unique_ptr` (or even a `shared_ptr`), and when the smart pointer that owns the memory goes out of scope, the memory is recycled.

This could happen when object containing `pint` is destroyed, or when `pint` goes out of scope as it was an automatic storage variable (on the stack), or when an exception is thrown past the destruction of `pint`.

Fancier versions of this require writing your own destructors.

One good tool to upgrade C-style resource management to C++-style RAII is a `scope_guard`, that runs arbitrary code on destruction.  (Be sure that destruction code cannot throw).

```
template<class F>
struct scope_guard {
  F f;
  bool bDoIt = true;
  scope_gaurd( F in ):f(std::move(in)) {}

  ~scope_guard() { run_now(); }
  void skip() { bDoIt = false; }
  bool run_now() {
    if (!bDoIt) return false;
    f();
    bDoIt = false;
    return true;
  }
  scope_guard(scope_guard const&)=delete;
  scope_guard(scope_guard && o):f(std::move(o.f)), bDoIt(o.bDoIt) {
    o.bDoIt = false;
  }
};
using storable_scope_guard = scope_guard<std::function<void()>>;
```

then you can do this:

```
auto atexit0 = scope_guard{ []{ /* recycle resources you just allocated */ } };
```

in your function body right after you allocate some resources that need cleaning up (as opposed to the C-style "do it manually at the end of the function, possibly with a bunch of gotos").

Comment: "If you create a named pipe, your OS cleanup won't work. If you make temporary files, your OS cleanup won't work.". Windows will clean up named pipes, and files provided the files were opened with `FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE`.

Comment: @MSalters added qualifications

Comment: *"This requires some discipline"*. I would say, "Not using RAII requires discipline." ;-)

Comment: @Jarod42 Oh, it requires zero discipline to not use RAII and leak resources all over the place.  ;)

Comment: @Jarod42 I go a bit further. "Not using RAII **deserves** discipline."